# Running java project with gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, gradle

I have a simple project with one class:

```
package hello;

import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
        System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I use a *build.gradle* file to build the project:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
}
```

And `gradle build` seems to be executed successfully from console:

```
d:\Spring\test\TestProject>gradle build
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/joda-time-2.2.pom
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/joda-time-2.2.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

But when I'm trying to run the application in Eclipse IDE with the following configuration:

[image]

the error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    LocalTime cannot be resolved to a type
    LocalTime cannot be resolved to a type

    at hello.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:8)
```

I've tried to execute `gradle clean` in console and then again `gradle build`, and than tried to run application in Eclipse again, but nothing changed.
Why does it happen? And how to fix it?

Comment: You need to have the buildship plugin installed (gradle eclipse plugin) and to import the gradle project, so tha eclipse configures the project build path based on the gradle configuration. Don't try to run a project if you still have compilation errors.

Comment: Try `gradle run`.

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you, it addressed my problem!